# R mcparallel mapReduce

Tags: r, mapreduce, multicore

I am looking for parallel version of aggregate() function and looks like http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mapReduce/mapReduce.pdf together with http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multicore/multicore.pdf is exactly what I am looking for.

So as a test I've created a dataset with 10m records

```
blockSize <- 5000
records <- blockSize * 2000
df <- data.frame(id=1:records, value=rnorm(records))
df$period <- round(df$id/blockSize)
# now I want to aggregate by period and return mean of every block:
x <- aggregate(value ~ period, data=df, function(x) { mean(x) })
# with mapReduce it can be done
library(multicore)
library(mapReduce)
jobId <- mcparallel(mapReduce(map=period, mean(value), data=df))
y <- collect(jobId)
```

but still somehow it doesn't utilise all 4 CPU cores on my laptop:

```
$ top
02:00:35 up 3 days, 18:14,  3 users,  load average: 1,61, 1,20, 0,79
Tasks: 237 total,   2 running, 235 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  : 17,4 us,  5,1 sy,  0,0 ni, 74,3 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  3,2 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu1  : 13,4 us,  6,9 sy,  0,0 ni, 79,7 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu2  : 21,3 us, 32,3 sy,  0,0 ni, 46,3 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
%Cpu3  : 17,0 us, 36,0 sy,  0,0 ni, 47,0 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   3989664 total,  3298340 used,   691324 free,    27248 buffers
KiB Swap:  7580668 total,  1154164 used,  6426504 free,   320360 cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
459 myuser    20   0 1850m 1,8g 1120 R  **99,1** 46,4   0:37.43 R
```

I use R 2.15.1:

```
R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22) -- "Roasted Marshmallows"
Copyright (C) 2012 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: i686-pc-linux-gnu (32-bit)
```

What am I doing wrong and how to aggregate huge datasets in R utilising multicore?

Thanks.

Comment: I was under the impression that `pkg:multicore` had been superseded by the `parallel` package which is now part of the Recommended bundle that ships with every installation of R. It's vignette's introductory sentences start: "Package parallel was first included in R 2.14.0. It builds on the work done for CRAN packages multicore (Urbanek, 2009–present) and snow (Tierney et al., 2003–present)  and provides drop- in replacements for most of the functionality of those packages..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How do you aggregate huge data sets in `R`?

Use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)


DT <- data.table(df)
setkey(DT, period)

DT[, list(value = mean(value)), by = period]
```

This will not use multiple cores, but will be extremely fast and memory efficient.

Comment: indeed, it works extremely fast without multicore. I'll try it tomorrow on the real dataset. Although I still would like to know how to aggregate() using multicore.

Comment: I'm on a windows machine, so such luxuries are not readily available, but it would seem that you should start by seeing if you can get `mcparallel` to work in parallel on a basic problem, or perhaps use te `apply` argument within `mapReduce` instead.

Comment: The use of `mcparallel` above makes no sense - you are executing *one* job in parallel and then collect it so it's the same as running it serially. In your case muticore won't be of much help, because computing the mean is an extremely fast operation so performing it in parallel will only slow things down. The most costly operation is the split which you have to do in either case with this approach. Just for completeness what you probably meant was simply `mapReduce(map=period, mean(value), data=df, apply=mclapply)` but as I said this will be actually slower than `aggregate`.